# How do I not re-render the entire list? memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I not re-render the entire list? There is a simple application, how to optimize and refactor it so that there are no unnecessary re-renders?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React, { useState, useCallback, memo } from "react";

const initList = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_el, index) => ({
    value: Math.random(),
    label: `row ${index + 1}`
  }));
}

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initList());

  const handleUpdate = useCallback(() => {
    setList((prevList) => {
      prevList[0].value = Math.random();

      return [...prevList];
    })
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List App</h1>
      <Button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update "row 1"</Button>
      {
        list.map(({ label, value }) => (
          <MRow key={value}>
            <b>{value}</b>
          </MRow>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

function Button(props) {
  const { children, onClick } = props;

  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
}

function Row(props) {
  const {
    label, value, children
  } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: '8px' }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

const MRow =  memo(Row, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.children.props.children === nextProps.children.props.children
})




ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.querySelector('#root')
).render(<App />)
```

So that there would be no unnecessary renderers How do I not re-render the entire list? There is a simple application, how to optimize and refactor it so that there are no unnecessary re-renders?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shared appears to already memoize the `Row` component and prevent "unnecessary rerenders". However, there are a few discrepancies and issues in the code.

1. The `initList` function is called each time the `App` component render, this is unnecessary work. Instead of invoking the `initList` function you can just pass the function reference to the `useState` hook and React will invoke it as a lazy initializer function once prior to the initial render.

   ```js
   const [list, setList] = .useState(initList);
   ```
2. The `handleUpdate` callback function mutates the first array element of the previous state then creates a shallow copy. Create the shallow state copy first, then also create a new object reference for the first array element, ***and then*** shallow copy it and update the `value` property.

   ```js
   const handleUpdate = useCallback(() => {
     setList((prevList) => {
       const nextList = prevList.slice(); // <-- shallow copy previous state

       nextList[0] = {        // <-- new object reference
         ...nextList[0],      // <-- shallow copy previous element
         value: Math.random() // <-- overwrite property
       };

       return nextList;       // <-- return new next state
     });
   }, []);
   ```
3. ***Don't*** use the `Row` component's `children` prop's `children` prop to check equality. Just pass the currently mapped row data to `Row` as props and check them instead.

   ```
   {list.map(({ label, value }) => (
     <MRow key={label} {...{ label, value }}>
       <b>{value}</b>
     </MRow>
   ))}
   ```

   ```js
   const MRow = React.memo(
     Row,
     (prevProps, nextProps) =>
       prevProps.value === nextProps.value && prevProps.label === nextProps.label
   );
   ```

### Demo

```js
function Button({ children, onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
}

function Row({ label, value, children }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Row render", JSON.stringify({ label, value }));
  });

  return <div style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}>{children}</div>;
}

const MRow = React.memo(
  Row,
  (prevProps, nextProps) =>
    prevProps.value === nextProps.value && prevProps.label === nextProps.label
);

const initList = () => {
  console.log("initList called");
  return Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_el, index) => ({
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    label: `row ${index + 1}`
  }));
};

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initList);

  const handleUpdate = React.useCallback(() => {
    setList((prevList) => {
      const nextList = prevList.slice();
      nextList[0] = {
        ...nextList[0],
        value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      };

      return nextList;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List App</h1>
      <Button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update "row 1"</Button>
      {list.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <MRow key={label} {...{ label, value }}>
          <b>{value}</b>
        </MRow>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```